# Converting model to tflite with SELECT_TF_OPS cannot convert ops HashTableV2 + others

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert [openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2](https://tfhub.dev/google/openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2/1) to tflite using the following code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650859/converting-pretrained-model-from-tfhub-to-tflite?noredirect=1#comment116176327_65691856):

```
import tensorflow as tf
MODEL_DIR = 'openimages_v4_ssd_mobilenet_v2_1'
SIGNATURE_KEYS = ['default']
SIGNATURE_TAGS = set()
saved_model = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_DIR, tags=SIGNATURE_TAGS)
tf.saved_model.save(saved_model, 'new_model_path', signatures=saved_model.signatures)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('new_model_path', signature_keys=SIGNATURE_KEYS, tags=['serve'])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

but it's giving this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': Ops that need custom implementation (enabled via setting the -emit-custom-ops flag):
    tf.HashTableV2 {container = "", device = "", key_dtype = i64, shared_name = "hub_input/index_to_string_1_load_0_3", use_node_name_sharing = true, value_dtype = !tf.string}
    tf.HashTableV2 {container = "", device = "", key_dtype = i64, shared_name = "hub_input/index_to_string_load_0_2", use_node_name_sharing = true, value_dtype = !tf.string}
    tf.LookupTableFindV2 {device = ""}
    tf.LookupTableImportV2 {device = ""}
```

I was able to get past these errors by adding:

```
 converter.allow_custom_ops = True
```

But according to [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37844#issuecomment-605336360) post on April 13, 2020:

> Removed AddHashtableOps support in Python temporarily. However, you can still add this to an interpreter in C++.

Is that still the case?  Also for the code snippet on how to use the tflite model in an [earlier comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37844#issuecomment-605336360) on that same issue, what should be imported in order to use the `interpreter_wrapper`?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select

In this documentation above it is clearly stated:

`Unsupported ops: Control flow ops and ops that require explicit initialization from resources, like HashTableV2, are not yet supported.`

Are you aware of this?

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable ops are custom ops in TFLite so you will need:
 `converter.allow_custom_ops = True` in order to convert your model.

The comment you mention is no longer valid. You can use AddHashtableOps in C++ or HashtableOpsRegisterer in python.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model_interpreter = tf.lite.interpreter.InterpreterWithCustomOps(
      model_content=tflite_model, custom_op_registerers=[HashtableOpsRegisterer])
```